# Custom Media Foundation sink never receives samples

Tags: c++, ms-media-foundation

I have my own `MediaSink` in Windows Media Foundation with one stream. In the `OnClockStart` method, I instruct the stream to queue (i) `MEStreamStarted` and (ii) `MEStreamSinkRequestSample` on itself. For implementing the queue, I use the `IMFMediaEventQueue`, and using the `mtrace` tool, I can also see that someone dequeues the event.

The problem is that `ProcessSample` of my stream is actually never called. This also has the effect that no further samples are requested, because this is done after processing a sample like in https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/DX11VideoRenderer.

Is the described approach the right way to implement the sink? If not, what would be the right way? If so, where could I search for the problem?

**Some background info:** The sink is an RTSP sink based on live555. Since the latter is also sink-driven, I thought it would be a good idea queuing a `MEStreamSinkRequestSample` whenever live555 requests more data from me. **This is working as intended.**

However, the solution has the problem that new samples are only requested as long as a client is connected to live555. If I now add a tee before the sink, eg to show a local preview, the system gets out of control, because the tee accumulates samples on the output of my sink which are never fetched. I then started playing around with discardable samples (cf. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/5065a7cd-3c63-43e8-8f70-be777c89b38e/mixing-rate-sink-and-rateless-sink-on-a-tee-node?forum=mediafoundationdevelopment), but the problem is either that the stream does not start, queues are growing or the frame rate of the faster sink is artificially limited depending on which side is discardable.

Therefore, the next idea was rewriting my sink such that it always requests a new sample when it has processed the current one and puts all samples in a ring buffer for live555 such that whenever clients are connected, they can retrieve their data from there, and otherwise, the samples are just discarded. This does not work at all. Now, my sink does not get anything even without the tee.

The observation is: if I just request a lot of samples (as in the original approach), at some point, I get data. However, if I request only one (I also tried moderately larger numbers up to 5), `ProcessSample` is just not called, so no subsequent requests can be generated. I send `MeStreamStarted` once the clock is started or restarted exactly as described on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms701626, and after that, I request the first sample. In my understanding, `MEStreamSinkRequestSample` should not get lost, so I should get something even on a single request. Is that a misunderstanding? Should I request until I get something?

Comment: The pipeline in general is [described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms701626), I suppose you read it. It's easy to make a mistake and debugging is complicated. E.g. you might be implementing event generator on media sink instead of stream sink. In general, media sink API is known to be working.

Comment: I know this page quite well and I think I built my sink according to the "Data Flow" section described there. However, it seems that requests can be lost somehow and I don't know why. I will add some background info to the question ...

Comment: One addition: The event generator is on the stream sink, ie once the media sink receives clock events, it loops over the audio and video stream and puts the initial `MEStreamSinkRequestSample` into the streams' event queues.

Comment: I am currently thinking about rewriting my live555 adapter class to use an `IMFSampleGrabberSinkCallback` instead of a custom sink such that I do not need to handle the requests myself. However, I do not see an option to get the actual media type from the sink wrapping the callback, which I would need to retrieve the `MF_MT_MPEG_SEQUENCE_HEADER` for live555 ...